# Best practices for Inversion of Control in libraries?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, prism, mef

I've been tasked with establishing code patterns to use for new applications that we'll be building. An early decision was made to build our applications and libraries using Prism & MEF with the intent of simplifying testing & reuse of functionality across applications.

As our code base has grown I've run into a problem.
Suppose we have some base library that needs access to some system - let's say a user management system:

```
public interface IUserManagementSystem
{
    IUser AuthenticateUser(string username, string password);
}
// ...
public class SomeClass
{
   [ImportingConstructor]
   public SomeClass(IUserManagementSystem userSystem){ }
}
```

We can now create an object of type SomeClass using the ServiceLocator, but ONLY if an implementation of IUserManagementSystem has been registered. There is no way to know (at compile-time) whether creation will succeed or fail, what implementations are needed or other critical information.

This problem becomes even more complicated if we use the ServiceLocator in the library.

Finding the now-hidden dependencies has become a bigger problem than hard-coded dependencies were in legacy applications. The IoC and Dependency Injection patterns aren't new, how are we supposed to manage dependencies once we take that job away from the compiler? Should we avoid using ServiceLocator (or other IoC containers) in library code entirely?

**EDIT**: I'm specifically wondering how to handle cross-cutting concerns (such as logging, communication and configuration). I've seen some recommendations for building a CCC project (presumably making heavy use of singletons). In other cases ([Is the dependency injection a cross-cutting concern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382560/is-the-dependency-injection-a-cross-cutting-concern)) the recommendation is to use the DI framework throughout the library leading back to the original problem of tracking dependencies.

[Dependency Inject (DI) "friendly" library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045904/dependency-inject-di-friendly-library) is somewhat relevant in that it explains how to structure code in a manner that can be used with or without a DI framework, but it doesn't address whether or not it makes sense to use DI *within* a library or how to determine the dependencies a given library requires. The marked answers there provide solid architectural advice about interacting with a DI framework but it doesn't address my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not be using ServiceLocator or any other DI-framework-specific pieces in your core library. That couples your code to the specific DI framework, and makes it so anyone consuming your library must also add that DI framework as a dependency for their product. Instead, use constructor injection and the various techniques [mentioned by Mark Seeman in his excellent answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2047657/120955).

Then, to help users of your library to get bootstrapped more easily, you can provide separate DI-Container-specific libraries with some basic utility classes that handle most of the standard DI bindings you're expecting people to use, so in many cases they can get started with a single line of code.

The problem of missing dependencies until run-time is a common one when using DI frameworks. The only real way around it is to use "poor-man's DI", where you have a class that actually defines how each type of object gets constructed, so you get a compile-time error if a dependency is introduced that you haven't dealt with.

However, you can often mitigate the problem by checking things as early in the runtime as possible. For example, SimpleInjector has a Validate() method that you can call after all the bindings have been set up, and it'll throw an exception if it can tell that it won't know how to construct dependencies for any of the types that have been registered to it. I also like adding a simple integration test to my testing suite that sets up all the bindings and then tries to construct all of the top-level types in my application (Web API Controllers, e.g.), and fails if it can't do so.

Comment: This is extremely valuable. One of the benefits of DI is that it helps us to write testable code. But the DI registration is itself complex code that needs to be tested.

Comment: Also, DO NOT use MEF with Prism.  MEF is not a DI container, and Prism is dropping support for MEF for a number of reasons.